# Issues with SonarQube 6.2, sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507 and Active Directory

Tags: sonarqube

Attempting to get LDAP working with SonarQube 6.2 and LDAP 2.1.  I have verified through various tools etc. that I can connect to LDAP on the server. These include LDAPExplorerTool2. I did have the old Active Directory plugin working on the same server with SonarQube prior to V6 but am forced to move to the LDAP plugin as the Active Directory plugin no longer works.  Here's my config section in sonar.properties

### Sonar.Properties

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.realm=mydomain.com
ldap.bindDn=mydomain.com/Service Accounts/username username
ldap.bindpassword=password
ldap.user.baseDn=OU=Global-Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
sonar.authenticator.downcase = true
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
```

Note: The LDAP information used is currently utilized for LDAP integration with Crucible, SVN, JIRA etc.

### sonar.log

```
Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.01.12 12:16:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp
2017.01.12 12:16:07 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: F:\Program Files\Java\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:F:\Program Files\Java\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process30466285842436995properties
2017.01.12 12:16:30 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.01.12 12:16:30 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: F:\Program Files\Java\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -server -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:F:\Program Files\Java\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process7120673276189616218properties
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: F:\Program Files\Java\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp -javaagent:F:\Program Files\Java\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\temp\sq-process4410592849159288958properties
2017.01.12 12:17:36 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
2017.01.12 12:17:36 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up
```

### web.log

```
2017.01.12 12:16:33 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.01.12 12:16:34 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2\web
2017.01.12 12:16:35 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-80"]
2017.01.12 12:16:35 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.01.12 12:16:38 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Aliyah Bishop] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.01.12 12:16:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2017.01.12 12:16:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.2 / 4a28f29f95254b58f3cf0a0871bc632e998403f5
2017.01.12 12:16:40 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SonarQube
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: F:\SonarQubeServer\sonarqube-6.2
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.5.2.537 / a4f663cf02cdcc88c221aaae7e7156fa4d176c07
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin CSS / Less / 2.4 / 5ac876d69f61a2c5fce597f3243bae45b8cd8f5f
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Code Smells / 3.0.0
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JSON / 2.2 / 0
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 4.4.0.8066 / 2703cce280bb210cffe8f8ac918df5f2c4d770f2
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.19.0.3866 / 97832288f366dae27584956414242e18dc96bca3
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin LDAP / 2.1.0.507 / 60b4a72c2042d0cad5233be63d0456815c9691e2
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Motion Chart / 1.7 / e9c4a5c95c75564b3c3b5a887b63ef50fc59a156
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.5.0.476 / 636872f5d37fa7a440fe07d08d504e1a881225e5
2017.01.12 12:16:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin XML / 1.4.1 / d2c0388961fcbe78ac597ca3fb3e262d3e733988
2017.01.12 12:16:47 DEBUG web[][o.s.c.p.PluginLoader] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin XML [xml] (built with API lower than 5.2)
2017.01.12 12:16:47 DEBUG web[][o.s.c.p.PluginLoader] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Motion Chart [motionchart] (built with API lower than 5.2)
2017.01.12 12:16:47 DEBUG web[][o.s.c.p.PluginLoader] API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
2017.01.12 12:16:48 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2017.01.12 12:16:48 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying app: motionchart
2017.01.12 12:16:48 DEBUG web[][o.s.c.i.DefaultI18n] Loaded 2159 properties from l10n bundles
2017.01.12 12:16:48 INFO  web[][o.s.d.c.MssqlCharsetHandler] Verify that database collation is case-sensitive and accent-sensitive
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages] Available languages:
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * C# => "cs"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * CSS => "css"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * Less => "less"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * Java => "java"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * Web => "web"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * XML => "xml"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * JSON => "json"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.a.r.Languages]   * JavaScript => "js"
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Auto discovery mode
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Detected server: ldap://myserver.mydomain.com:389
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=OU=Global-Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com, request=(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0})), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}
2017.01.12 12:16:51 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Groups will not be synchronized, because property 'ldap.group.baseDn' is empty.
2017.01.12 12:16:51 DEBUG web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldap://myserver.mydomain.com:389, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.security.principal=mydomain.com/Service Accounts/username username, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.security.sasl.realm=mydomain.com, java.naming.referral=follow}
2017.01.12 12:16:53 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://myserver.mydomain.com:389: OK
2017.01.12 12:16:53 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
2017.01.12 12:16:53 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2017.01.12 12:16:54 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2017.01.12 12:16:54 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics (done) | time=189ms
2017.01.12 12:16:54 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2017.01.12 12:17:02 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules (done) | time=7631ms
2017.01.12 12:17:02 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2017.01.12 12:17:05 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles (done) | time=2804ms
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2017.01.12 12:17:05 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates (done) | time=7ms
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index authorization
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index project measures
2017.01.12 12:17:05 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.p.ServerLifecycleNotifier] Notify ServerStartHandler handlers...
2017.01.12 12:17:05 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.p.ServerLifecycleNotifier] Notify ServerStopHandler handlers...
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_92-b14 [Windows Server 2008 R2-amd64]
2017.01.12 12:17:05 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@7a466ac8 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@2032ab0]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@3c2de9ba [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@7574d4dd]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@56dc8673 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@5efc52b]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction@439ebae8 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@38a3f92d]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.ValidateAction@74b498ab [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@42cb352f]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-80"]
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.01.12 12:17:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 80
2017.01.12 12:34:53 DEBUG web[AVmTvuWHWxcly44dAAAJ][o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] Requesting details for user myuser
2017.01.12 12:34:53 DEBUG web[AVmTvuWHWxcly44dAAAJ][o.s.p.l.LdapSearch] Search: LdapSearch{baseDn=OU=Global-Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com, scope=subtree, request=(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0})), parameters=[myuser], attributes=[mail, cn]}
2017.01.12 12:34:53 ERROR web[AVmTvuWHWxcly44dAAAJ][o.s.s.a.RealmAuthenticator] Error during authentication
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapSearch.find(LdapSearch.java:125)
at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapSearch.findUnique(LdapSearch.java:142)
at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapUsersProvider.getUserDetails(LdapUsersProvider.java:80)
at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapUsersProvider.doGetUserDetails(LdapUsersProvider.java:58)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:89)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.authenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:83)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:56)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:45)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.authenticate(LoginAction.java:91)
at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.doFilter(LoginAction.java:76)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried a few different things, including specifying an LDAP URL to a known LDAP server (one of the auto discovered ones).  I tried specifying the port as 3268 and 389 for these servers but it has not made any difference.

I also tried running the LDAP query (&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=myuser)) on LDAP Explorer and it returns data.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapSearch.find(LdapSearch.java:125)
```

Looking at the source line 125 of LDAPSearch is

```
context = contextFactory.createBindContext();
```

The complete code snippet is

```
public NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> find() throws NamingException {
  LOG.debug("Search: {}", this);
  NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result;
  InitialDirContext context = null;
  boolean threw = false;
  try {
    context = contextFactory.createBindContext();
    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
    controls.setSearchScope(scope);
    controls.setReturningAttributes(returningAttributes);
    result = context.search(baseDn, request, parameters, controls);
    threw = true;
  } finally {
    ContextHelper.close(context, threw);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To verify (because it's not actually included in your question): your server's not connecting to LDAP? Or once it does, authentication fails? What's the exact symptom of your problem?

Comment: the logs would seem to indicate it's able to connect to LDAP, [2017.01.12 12:16:53 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://myserver.mydomain.com:389: OK] but when it's attempting to authenticate my user it falls over doing an LDAP search.  So I just get an Authentication failed message and the logs above show it's failed

Comment: Oh and just to add..  I can login using the internal admin user.

Comment: I see the exception now (I'm skeptical that we really need the full web log from startup, but okay). Is there a 'caused by' on that exception?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you.  What I've posted is the complete log, where would I see the 'caused by'?

Comment: I have entered a post on the SonarQube google groups.  I did some debugging and believe I have found a bug in the LDAP code.  I will post more details as they become available.  For anyone who is interested this is a link to that post.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/oU4FSb8rKEE

Comment: After having made a local fix to the plugin (and correcting my sonar.properties entry ldap.bindpassword should be ldap.bindPassword) I can now access SonarQube with LDAP Auto Discovery.  I will update when someone from SonarQube responds to my group post on google.groups.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I got the same issue. The bug ticket is still open. https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/LDAP-60